# Forward non-local connections from router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am using a SMC router/modem. I have a server running on my computer accepting connections at port 8000

I set up a Customer Defined Service Table for an HTTP service to accept connections at port 800 and forward to my LAN IP.

I have a server running on my machine at port 8000 serving out content. However, when I type: 
my-ip-address:8000, i cant seem to connect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting from inside the network, you need to use the internal ip address.  If you are connecting from the server, you need to use localhost:8000 instead of the IP.  If you use the external IP address, be sure to do it from outside the network.

ps- I am assuming when you say port 800 in the second paragraph you mean 8000.  If not that could be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

JNK's answer is correct, however, if you can and set up "SNAT" or "MASQUARADE" for NAT on the router, you will be able to use "public_ip:8000" even from inside your  network.